# onClick visibility toggler not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, post, onclick

I'm starting with some basis php, and injected my (working before) javascipt "tabs patent" to have everything in one place.

I've got two forms here in two 'sections' , after clicking "sign up" button, the first 'login' section hides out, and the 'sign up' section show up. But it shows up only on a second (blink ones), can You check what is wrong here?

the 'sign up' section is hidden by default in the css stylesheet, and then after clicking the button, the javascript code changes visibility value, but why it blink only ones and hide again?

js

```
function showSignup () {
            document.getElementById("signup").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("login").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
function showLogin () {
            document.getElementById("signup").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("login").style.visibility = "visible";
        }
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/base-min.css">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" ></script>
</head>

<body>

<section id="login">

    <form action="login.php" method="post"> 
        <p>your login: <input type="text" name="login" value="" /> </p>
        <p>your pass: <input type="text" name="pass" value="" /> </p>
        <p> <input type="submit" value="send" /> </p> 
    </form>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <p><input type="submit" value="sign up" onclick="showSignup()" /> </p>
    </form>

</section>

<section id="signup">

    <form method="post">

        <h2>Create new account</h2>
        <p>login: <input type="text" name="slogin" value="" /></p>
        <p>e-mail: <input type="text" name="semail" value="" /></p>
        <p>password: <input type="text" name="spass" value="" />  </p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Sign Up" /> </p>

    </form>

    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

css

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}
section {
    position: relative;
    margin: 2em auto;
    padding: 1em;
    border: solid gray 2px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 400px;
}
#signup {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
#login {
    position: absolute;
}
```

I made an jsfiddle, but it shows me an error after clicking "sign up" button

```
{"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_lib', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0x40fda90>, 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_lib', 'label': u'Js lib', 'field': <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0x40fda10>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_wrap', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0x40fda90>, 'html_name': 'js_wrap', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_wrap', 'label': u'Js wrap', 'field': <django.forms.fields.TypedChoiceField object at 0x4512190>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_wrap'}"}
```

why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your submit button of the second form in the section with id "login" triggers the form and therefor reloads the page.

So you can either prevent the form from submitting with JavaScript or change the input-type to button.

Answer (score 0):

You've attached the function to a submit button in a form. When you click it, the JavaScript runs and then the form submits which **loads a new page**.

Use a regular button and don't use a form.